# Converting PCM to AMR-WB using AmrInputStream

Tags: android, android-audiorecord, amr

My Android application needs to convert recorded audio in WAV to AMR-NB and AMR-WB.
And i am done with converting to **AMR-NB** using **AmrInputStream**.

In AmrInputStream, the value for SAMPLES_PER_FRAME is hard coded to **8000 * 20 / 1000**  and the audio has no changes even after changing SAMPLES_PER_FRAME to **(16000*20/1000)**.

Is it possible to convert PCM to **AMR-WB (16 khz)** using AmrInputStream ?

Comment: The fact that this class is hidden and not mentioned in the official documentation is probably a hint that you shouldn't be using it. You could take a look at the [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) API. It requires API level 16 or above, though.

Comment: my app targets android 2.2 and later.Any other solution?